# Product of Odd Functions

Tags: functions

So I'm working on a mini-project for my intro proof writing course and we're given the following that I'm a little hung up on.

Consider $V$ to be a known vector space and functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f:V->R$ and $g:V->R$

Prove or disporve: The product of two odd functions is odd.

Which I've interpreted as:  If $f$ and $g$ are both odd functions, then $f*g$ is odd.

Now if we were working strickly in the Reals, I would know this to be false, however the domain being a "known vector space" has me a bit thrown...  My initial work was as follows:

Consider an $x$ in $V$ such that $x=-x$.  Then $f(-x)=-f(x)$ [by definition of odd function] and $g(-x)=-g(x)$.

Then $(f*g)(-x)=f(-x)*g(-x)=[-f(x)][-g(x)]=f(x)g(x)=(f*g)(x)$ which is not $-(f*g)(x)$

However, the tiny bit of feed back that I've been given is "how do I know that $x$ is in $V$"

So I'm stuck.  Can I find a known vector space that the properties of odd functions holds up?  If I were working in the reals, I could come up (easily that is) with specific odd functions and show that their product is not odd... I thought perhaps I could do everything in general but my feedback has pushed me in a different direction...

One random thought I had was that the antecedent in my statement is false, that is, there are no functions $f$ and $g$ that are odd, thus the antecedent is false rendering the statement true but I think that is off base....

I could use a little direction here.  :)  Thanks.

Comment: Well that is obvious now... My thoughts were that I needed show that there exists an element in V such that f*g(-x) does not equal -(f*g)(x) That my negation implies an exstistentially quantified variable.

Comment: I think that you’re working too hard: $$(fg)(-x)=f(-x)g(-x)=\big(-f(x)\big)\big(-g(x)\big)=f(x)g(x)=(fg)(x)\;.$$ Thus, if there is any $x\in V$ such that $(fg)(x)\ne\vec 0$, $fg$ isn’t odd. But what if $\ker fg=V$?

Comment: Again, this is fairly trivial if we're dealing with functions from R to R and perhaps I am just way overthinking things but I was explicitly asked how that I know x is in V?  I know my prof is trying to get me to think but I feel as if he's trying to get me to define the vector space such that x is an element and f and g are odd functions from V to R...

Comment: What I wrote has nothing specifically to do with functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$; it applies to functions from any real vector space to $\Bbb R$. I’m reasonably sure that you were asked how you know that your $x$ with $x=-x$ is in $V$ simply in order to get you to realize that it must be the zero vector. And no, you’re not being asked to define $V$.

Comment: What am I missing here? The product of two odd functions is even per Brian's proof above. That $-x\in V$ follows from the axioms of a vector space. Any scalar times a vector is in the space. Every field has $-1$. It is the additive inverse of the multiplicative identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Take a basis $B$ of $V$ and a specific basis element $b \in B$. Then for each $x$ in $V$ write $x=k\cdot b + ...$ and define $f(x)=g(x)=k$. These each map $V \to \mathbb{R}$ and are the identity on the one dimensional subspace generated by $b$. They are also both odd functions (easy to check), yet their product is not an odd function (also needs to be checked). I think this gives a concrete counterexample as long as the vector space $V$ is assumed to have a basis, which isn't much of a restriction, and perhaps the idea here might work even without a basis, though I don't see that now.

NOTE: The above argument fails if the vector space $V$ is over a field of characteristic $2$. However in such vector spaces $x=-x$ for all $x$ and there is really no notion of odd versus even functions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you’re working with vector spaces over the real numbers, or perhaps the complex numbers. Thus, if $x=-x$, then $2x=\vec 0$, and $x=\vec 0$, so there’s no problem.